# How to set a background timer, and stop a function when it finishes while still waiting for reactions

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

So I'm making some minigame using discord.py, and this is what I got:

```py
asyncio.create_task(self.stream_message_timer(ctx, correct, total), name=f"stream message timer {ctx.author.id}")
while bad_count > 0:
    
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([
        self.client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: str(reaction.emoji) in number_emojis and reaction.message.id == discord_message.id and user == ctx.author),
        self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == self.client.user and m.content == f"Times up!\n{correct}/{total} tasks successful.")
    ], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    try:
        result = done.pop().result()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    for future in done:
        future.exception()

    for future in pending:
        future.cancel()

    if type(result) == discord.Message:
        return False
    else:
        reaction = result

    # process the reaction, edit a message

await ctx.send(f"You deleted all the bad messages!\n{correct+1}/{total} tasks successful.")

for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
    if task.get_name() == f"stream message timer {ctx.author.id}":
        task.cancel()
        break

return True

async def stream_message_timer(self, ctx, correct, total):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send(f"Times up!\n{correct}/{total} tasks successful.") # message linked to delete_chat, change there if this is changed
        return False
```

Basically, I'm trying to make some kind of 5 second background timer as I wait for reactions at the same time.
*No, I am* **not** *looking for* `timeout=5`

The code that I have here works, but its very hacky. I'm either waiting for a reaction from the user, or just waiting for the bot to message "Times up".

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I would like to have the timer start right before the while loop, and forcefully stop anything inside the loop and make the function return False right when the timer finishes

Also, if the function does stop, I still want some way to cancel the timer, and that timer only.
I've been using this method for quite some time and it's making my code very unorganized. Thanks.

Here’s some sort of example that is independent from discord.py:

```py
import asyncio
import random

async def main():

     asyncio.create_task(timer(), name="some task name")
     # simulates waiting for user input
     await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5))
    return True

async def timer():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    # somehow make this return statement stop the main() function
    return False 

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Could you edit the answer to create a self-contained runnable example, i.e. something that doesn't depend on discord and the classes defined in your project? That will make it much easier to understand and improve the code.

Comment: @user4815162342 I’ve edited it now, if that helps

Comment: Thanks, but the example doesn't appear to be _runnable_. A runnable example would make it possible to experiment with your code, and then improve it for clarity.

Comment: I can't think of another situation where I am `await`ing for a user's input..

Comment: You can emulate waiting for user's input with asyncio.sleep or similar. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details about providing a reproducible example.

Comment: @user4815162342 Alright, edited it again. Take a look at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` is the correct way to do it, but you can simplify the invocation (and subsequent cancellation) by using the return value of `create_task`:

```
async def main():
    timer_task = asyncio.create_task(timer())
    user_input_task = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5)))
    await asyncio.wait([timer_task, user_input_task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    if not timer_task.done():
        timer_task.cancel()

    if user_input_task.done():
        # we've finished the user input
        result = await user_input_task
        ...
    else:
        # we've timed out
        await timer_task   # to propagate exceptions, if any
        ...
```

If this pattern repeats a lot in your code base, you can easily abstract it into a utility function.